# How to exclude mapping entity in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a strange question here, forgive me if I am wrong.

My question here is, I have a ManyToOne mapping defined for two entities in my application. When deleting I want to ignore deleting of other entity.

Suppose Emp to Dept has ManyToOne relation, and I am deleting Emp record through session.delete(EmpId), at this time I don't want to delete Dept associated to Emp entity.

I cant change cascade option in hbm.

scenario is something like

> " if there are 10 emps belonging to dept number 101 and while deleting
>   any one emp it will try to delete the associated Dept also which is
>   not possible as we have some other emp records belonging to same dept"

So is there a way to ignore deleting dept record while deleting emp record pro-grammatically. Why pro-grammatically is, but here I need to consider cascade option when deleting last emp record associated to dept 101 record. And I don't want to consider cascade option while deleting prior 9 emp objects.

Please suggest me work around for this scenario.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: *I cant change cascade option in hbm.*  why ?

Comment: what kind of mapping are you using ?? xml or annotation???

Comment: @ben75, I cant change hbm because we are importing some part of model objects and hbms from another imported jar, in which we cant do any alterings.

Comment: @Dev, We are using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting it with HQL, it ignores cascade configuration.

```
session.createQuery("delete from Employee where id = ?").setParameter(0, empId).executeUpdate();
```

However if there are other entities already loaded into Hibernate session which still reference the one you deleted, you might get `EntityNotFoundException`. You will have to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I have created Entity classes like below to explain my answer in proper way ,

> Note:- Entity classes are only my assumption you might be implementing
>   it with differently

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Emp implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long empId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Dpt department;

    other property
    ... getter() setter()
}

@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
public class Dpt implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long dptId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Set<Emp> employeeSet;

    other property
    ... getter() setter()
}
```

As per your requirement I have created bi-directional association in above code snippet

Problem 1

> Suppose Emp to Dept has ManyToOne relation, and I am deleting Emp record through session.delete(EmpId), at this time I don't want to delete Dept associated to Emp entity.

Answer
here you are performing

```
session.delete(EmpId)
```

in your code if you are doing something like below

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPARTMENT_ID",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Dpt department;

     or

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPARTMENT_ID",cascade=CascadeType.DELETE)
    private Dpt department;
```

then only JPA try to delete parent (Dpt) while deleting child(Emp)

> Note::- Never use cascade with @ManyToOne

Here if you remove cascade from @ManyToOne should resolve your issue (deleting parent (Dpt) while deleting child(Emp))

Problem 2

> I need to consider cascade option when deleting last emp record
>   associated to dept 101 record. And I don't want to consider cascade
>   option while deleting prior 9 emp objects.

You can handle above case scenario programmaticly , for 9 emp objects you can 
use

```
 session.delete(EmpId)
```

and for 10th employee

```
session.delete(DptId)
```

Here in above code I have used

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
        private Set<Emp> employeeSet;
```

Here functioning of `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` is to delete all child(Emp) entity if parent(Dpt) entity is removed  ,in your case removing Dpt entity also removes your last Emp  record associated with that department

Hope this will help you

Thanks!!

Comment: OP said he can't change cascade options, entities are imported from another project.

Comment: I have just describe possible case scenario of occurrence of error in above question.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. As we did not have a work around for this user story for that sprint i did not look for a solution by that time.Any how we have a work around for this, now we changed the requirement to delete all child records then parent record. Earlier they dont want to delete  all child records for reporting purpose, now we delete all records so no issue.